# JDBC. Replace in all rows value of the column

Tags: java, jdbc

Java 11. PostgreSQL.

Having following table in db:

```
TABLE public.account (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    account_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    display_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    is_deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
);
```

There are about 1000 rows in this table. In the code I have a static method, which return random string - Helper.getRandomName()

How, using JDBC, in this table (public.account) for all rows replace "display_name" value with value of Helper.getRandomName()?

Comment: Do you want all rows to get the same value, or do you want each row to get a different value? If the last, you are probably better off generating the random name using a SQL function.

Comment: I want each row to get a different value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL question. You need to run an update query:

```sql
UPDATE public.account set display_name = ?
```

And provide the new name as the parameter. The absence of a `WHERE` clause means that all rows will be affected.

If you want to do this for each row individually, then it's harder. You'll want to do a select statement to find all the IDs, and then you can prepare a batch of updates using JDBC, adding a where clause for each ID.

JDBC is just a thin Java wrapper around plain SQL execution.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use an updatable result set and update through the result set, but that will usually translate to individual row update statements below the surface.

Comment: I want to do this for each row individually, so each row would have unique value.